# REST API Search images

Tags: javascript, search, rest, image

I'm doing a simple REST request to the SharePoint API and it seems that it doesn't retrieve images or videos, should I add something specific to the query text in order to have images and videos in my results?

The query I'm using is:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext=%27(-FileExtension:aspx)(-FileExtension:one)%27&rowlimit=50
```

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: Sharepoint Online/ O365

Answer (score 0):

Images are not indexed by default unless you put them in Picture Libraries. You can test this by querying `FileExtension:jpg`. Videos depend on how you uploaded them. If you are using the SharePoint Video content type, excluding .aspx may be your issue. What happens when you search for `ContentType:Video`?

On-Prem you can change the files indexed, you cannot in Office 365, so choosing an appropriate location is often your best bet.

Start by changing your query to only include the items you seek.